# Query on two DataTable to find duplicate rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have an excel sheet which i am uploading to sqlserver table using sqlbulkcopy, i have applied an index on database table so that duplicate entries are ignored but i also want to display the duplicate entries which were ignored in a grid view.

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToString().ToLower();
    string strFileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();

    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Import/" + strFileName + strFileType));
    string strNewPath = Server.MapPath("~/Import/" + strFileName + strFileType);






        string excelConnectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source="+strNewPath +"; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

    //string excelConnectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=C:\\myFolder\\Book1.xls;" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"); 


        // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select ID,Data FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
            OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from [Sheet1$]",connection);

            //Sql Server Table DataTable
            DataTable dt4=new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select id,data from ExcelTable", con);
            try 
                { 
                    SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4); 
                    da4.Fill(dt4);//sql table datatable
                 }
                catch { }


            //excelsheet datatable
            DataTable oltlb = new DataTable();
          OleDbCommand olcmd = new OleDbCommand("select id,data from [Sheet1$]", connection);
          try
          {
              OleDbDataAdapter olda = new OleDbDataAdapter(olcmd);
              olda.Fill(oltlb); //excel table datatable
          }
          catch { }

    var matched = (from table1 in dt4.AsEnumerable()
                         join table2 in oltlb.AsEnumerable() on
                       table1.Field<int>("ID") equals table2.Field<int>("ID")
                         where table1.Field<string>("Data") == table2.Field<string>("Data")
                         select table1);
          DataTable dthi5 = new DataTable();
          dthi5 = matched.CopyToDataTable();

          GridView1.DataSource = dthi5;
          GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.DataSource = matched.ToList();
```

ERROR:
Specified cast is not valid.
table1.Field("ID") equals table2.Field("ID")

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the ID field in one of your tables is not an int.

Rather than one or both of us guessing, try inspecting the data type of the first column in both tables (oltlb and dt4) to see which has the non-integer data type.  It may in fact be both.

Here's the thing:  even if the value of a string is a numeric literal, you can't cast a string to an int.  You'd have to use `Int32.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` to convert.  So if one of your tables has a string type for the ID column, you would express it like this:

```
table1.Field<int>("ID") equals Convert.ToInt32(table2.Field<string>("ID"))
```

If both of the tables have a string ID field, you could just express it this way:

```
table1.Field<string>("ID") equals table2.Field<string>("ID")
```

Comment: What data types are the first columns of the two tables?

Comment: first table is sql table int and second table is the one i am deriving from excel sheet

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the "var matched" line.  Run your code in Debug.  When it reaches the break point, in the Immediate window, type `? oltlb.Columns[0].DataType` and hit Enter.  What does it say?

Comment: i am getting error in 
Convert.ToInt32(table2.Field<string>("ID"))
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: OK, that will be easy to fix.  Change it to `Convert.ToInt32(table2.Field<Double>("ID"))`.